# Looping thru two list and check data

Tags: python, list, loops

The lists below are just for example purpose.
I have two lists by which the both lists need to have the same order. I need to print out the data in `out_list` that is not in order - `3` for this example. But i do not know how to make the loop.

```
in_list =[1,2,3,4]
out_list =[1,3,2,4]
temp_list =[]
for out in out_list: 
    if out == in_list[0]:
        in_list.pop(0) 
    else:
        temp_list.append(out)

out_list = temp_list
print('in', in_list)
print('out', out_list)
```

The output for this code is

```
in [3, 4]
out [3, 4]
```

Meanwhile, my desired output is

```
in []
out [3]
```

Comment: Two questions, why is 2 not considered to be out of order? And under what conditions are you wanting to print no values from the in_list?

Comment: though not exact this is this ur looking for out_list = [1, 3, 2, 4]

new = sorted(out_list)

for f, b in zip(out_list, new):
    if f != b:
        print("Element not sorted : " + str(b))
Element not sorted : 2
Element not sorted : 3

Comment: If 3 is out of order then so is 2. Can you clarify your requirement?